# laravel telescope nothing to migrate

Tags: laravel

i have a laravel 6 app that i want to install the telescope in that i did all the commands like `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` and then i install the telescope every thing is going fine and when i run `php artisan telescope:install` i get the message below :

```
Publishing Telescope Service Provider...
Publishing Telescope Assets...
Publishing Telescope Configuration...
Telescope scaffolding installed successfully.
```

but it wont generate the config file and migration so when i run `php artisan migrate` i get this message :

> nothing to migrate

Answer (score 10):

in your command

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations
```

then edit you your env file

```
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true
```

after this run

```
php artisan optimize
```

Finally

> php artisan migrate

Comment: I had telescope disabled because of that setting in a copied .env file. Publishing telescope config is optional.

Answer (score 2):

You must publish it first using the below command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations
```

Then you will get the default migrations and also the `config/telescope.php` file

Comment: Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.


Publishing Telescope Service Provider...
Publishing Telescope Assets...
Publishing Telescope Configuration...
Telescope scaffolding installed successfully.



nothing to migrate

Comment: after  your advise     i got this

Comment: To be fair though, [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope#installation) just states: "_After installing Telescope, publish its assets using the telescope:install Artisan command. After installing Telescope, you should also run the migrate command_"

Comment: then i cant see the telescope.php

Comment: so u just told  me   1composer require laravel/telescope    2php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations  3  php artisan telescope:install 4migrate??????????

Comment: the common telescop is

Comment: Does this line exist in your env file? 
`TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true`

Run `php artisan optimize` after you put it, and then try to run migrations again.

Comment: oh sorry  let me to do taht

Comment: let me try that

Comment: i am trying for that but  i got this message from my cli 
  Class 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Yeah, that's  common issue. Inside your vendor you must find this provider, and manually copy and paste this class into your providers. Basically find this class inside your vendor and move it to your providers in your project in `App/Providers`

Comment: i cant found that  provider in my vendor does any way to remove the vendor and install again then i will going to composer install and install telescop     or   how can i found that in vendor if exist   or can u tell me the specific path   (im sorry about my bad englsh  but i understand u as well )

Comment: `php artisan telescope:install` This command should do all this automatically, did you run it after all the steps we did? If it still not working, inside your vendor there is a telescope folder. Search in there for the provider. Also did you install the normal version or the --dev?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212135/discussion-between-ehsan-and-pr1nc3).

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `telescope` in my project and exporting the default migration I got this error.

```
λ php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations
Unable to locate publishable resources.
Publishing complete.
```

**How I solve this issue**

If you're getting this issue open `telescope.php` file which is inside of your `config` directory.

and then set the value of this `TELESCOPE_ENABLED` to `true`

```
'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_ENABLED', true),
```

Because in my case the value of `TELESCOPE_ENABLED` this was `false`

Then again run this command `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=telescope-migrations`.
I hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally ran `php artisan optimize` in my local environment which was causing this issue. To fix it, I had to run `php artisan optimize:clear`, then uninstall `laravel/telescope`, remove any references to it, and install it again from scratch. It then recognised the migrations and the published assets.

Answer (score 0):

I did this

> composer remove laravel/telescope

Then change your .env file

> TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true

Then install back again it worked!

Comment: nothing, not work